# Small clock icon above AM/PM on 4x2 clock widget

Tags: samsung, app-widgets

Just received JellyBean 4.1.2 on my Sprint Samsung Galaxy S3. I have always used the 4x2 digital clock widget and I noticed a small icon that looks like a clock appearing just above the AM/PM. This also appears when displaying the weather for the various cities. What does it mean?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to make it easier for us to see? We cannot see it from here :D

Comment: Ya screenshot would be nice, but it might be an edit button to change the appearance of the widget.  Could the icon possibly look like a gear?

Comment: Is it an indicator that an alarm is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by your description, you're referring to the object circled in this screenshot

[image]

That thing indicates that the city the time is being shown for is currently running on daylight savings time.  In this screenshot, we see that New York is observing daylight savings time, and Phoenix isn't.

Comment: That's it. I'm trying not to be so curious considering what that does to cats

Comment: @SusieB - Curiosity was framed for that.  =)